# JAXB: list of strings as attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a normal instance variable of `List<String>`. How can I convert it to XML such that the values within the list are added as `XmlAttributes` instead of `XmlValue`

```
<book id="123"/>
<book id="456"/>
<book id="789"/>
```

instead of

```
<book>123</book>
<book>456</book>
<book>789</book>
```

One option I see is to have List of custom object that wraps the String values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a

```
class BookType {
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String id;
    //...
}
```

and make the `List<String>` into a

```
    @XmlElement
    List book;
```

Comment: Yes, already mentioned this approach in the question. Seems that this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [@XmlElement](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html) like

```
@XmlElement(name = "book")
List<String> books
```

Comment: It gives me list values as node text instead of attribute value, which I already mentioned

Comment: Yes sorry. I think you need write @XmlJavaTypeAdapter.